# Is there a non-metrizable topological space for which any countably compact subset is compact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness

The title is the question : Is there a non-metrizable topological space for which any countably compact subset is compact ?

EDIT : **non-metrizable and Hausdorff**

Comment: To the OP: if you register your original account you will be able to make edits without waiting for approval.  If you no longer have that cookie set, you can make a new account and ask for it to be [merged](http://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts) with the original one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any Lindelöf non-metrizable Hausdorff space will do (EDIT: you need that the space is C-closed as well, see below), but more generally, a space is called isocompact iff every closed countably compact subset of X is compact, cl-isocompact iff the closure of a countably compact subset is compact, and C-closed iff any countably compact subset is closed. This paper by Cho and Park contains various results on (cl)-isocompactess, as well a other references:

http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/978637.pdf

And this one by Ismail and Nyikos has good informations on C-closed spaces:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864180900279

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the above examples, it might be of interest that functional analysis is awash with such spaces.  For example, the space of distributions on a compact interval or that of functions analytic on a closed domain in the complex plane, both with their natural topologies.  More generally, any Silva space has this property.  A further ubiquitous source of examples is the dual of a separable Banach space with the bounded weak $\ast$ topology.  A suitable reference would be Köthe's classic on topological linear spaces.

Comment: And $\ell_1$ (or even its unit ball) with the weak topology.

Comment: The space $\mathscr D'(\Omega)$ of distributions on an *open* set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ also has the property because it is a *strict* (locally convex) inductive limit of Frechet spaces.

Comment: Warning: both of these comments contain false statements.

Comment: @vltava: Could you be more specific?

Comment: The unit ball of $\ell^1$ is metrisable and so not a counterexample, the space of distributions is not a strict $LF$-space.

Comment: @vltava The unit ball in $\ell_1$ is not weakly metrizable. See Proposition 3.106 in "Banach space theory" by Fabian et al (Springer 2011).

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were referring to the weak $\ast$ topology.

Answer (score 5):

I think any compact, first countable, non-metrizable Hausdorff space suffices, since then any countably compact set is closed and hence compact.  In Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*, #95, the weak parallel line topology, has these properties.